# Boot memtest86 from hard drive

Tags: boot, grub, memtest86+, memtest

Is it possible to boot into memtest86 from the hard drive (i.e. add it to my Grub menu), without burning it to a CD/USB, or creating an extra partition.

I expect it should be possible, because Debian does have memtest86+ in its repositories, as well as a very old version of memtest86. Memtest86+ will not work on my system because it is UEFI, and I'm not even going to bother with an outdated version of memtest86.

EDIT:
Just to make sure we are all on the same page here, I want memtest86 (without the +), not memtest86+.

Comment: Do these help at all? https://askubuntu.com/questions/126160/how-can-i-add-the-memtest86-options-back-to-the-grub-menu

Comment: @MC10 - Not really. That is for memtest86+ (note the `+`), which appears in my Grub menu when I install it, but does not work because it is not compatible with UEFI

Comment: What I need is to get Grub to boot any one of the images found here: https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm

Comment: Installing memtest86+ to your HDD will not change the fact it's a 16-bit application which is the reason it does not support UEFI mode.  Your criteria of NOT having a bootable media and/or partition does not make sense

Comment: It does not make sense, because you only skimmed through what I wrote... I do not want memtest86+, I want memtest86